# Rmarkdown and gt::caption placed at bottom of table/output?

Tags: r, r-markdown, gt

this recently came up with the gt:: package but I also remember this from kableExtra as well iirc.

I'm trying to both use the packages title option but also RMarkdowns `fig.cap`.

Is there a way to enable both or do I have to work around it, for example with `{{captioneer}}` ?

edit: this question has been solved using `gt::gt(caption = "xy")`

Next: is it possible to place this caption at the bottom of the table?

Thanks!

````
---
title: "gt caption"
author: ""
date: "10 5 2022"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Header

```{r, fig.cap="I also want this fig.cap", echo = FALSE}
tab <- gt::gt(pressure, caption = "xy")

tab <- gt::tab_header(tab,
title = gt::md(
  "Title via tab_header"))
tab
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the caption argument in gt() with gt::tab_footnote()

```
tab <- gt::gt(pressure) 
tab <- gt::tab_footnote(tab, footnote = "xy")

tab <- gt::tab_header(tab,
title = gt::md(
  "Title via tab_header"))
tab
```

[image: example]